# Create blank Word docs automatically using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create N number of blank word documents. The filenames for each word doc will be given in a txt or excel file. What's the efficient way to automate this using Python.

Comment: Have you look at: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, first you willl need to store the filenames, if they are stored in a txt file:

```
names = open('path/to/your/file.txt', "r").readlines()#here you suppose that you have a name per line
```

then you have to create the files so:

```
path = 'path/were/you/want/to/store/'

for name in names:

    file = open(path + name.strip('\n') + ".docx", "x")
    file.close()
```

Comment: It is not creating docs but simply reading the contents of the text file I  passed as input

Comment: no, the loop will create a docx file for every name in your txt file